# Design patterns/best practice for building Actor-based system

Tags: scala, erlang, actor

I am struggling to find any decent links to design patterns, best practice or good, basic architectural principles that should be used in building Actor-based apps. Those few that I know of are:

#### Blog posts, articles, WIKIs, guides

- [OTP Design Principles User's Guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/users_guide.html)
- [Patterns and Best Practices for Enterprise Integration](http://www.eaipatterns.com/) (in general, can be applied to any message-driven architecture)
- Series of [posts by James Iry on dealing with state in design with actors](http://james-iry.blogspot.com/search/label/parallel%2Fdistributed%2Fconcurrent)
- Series of [posts on design with Scala actors](http://www.tikalk.com/category/tags/scala-actors) by Ittay Dror
- [Concurrency patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_pattern) article on wikipedia
- [Scalable System Design Patterns](http://horicky.blogspot.com/2010/10/scalable-system-design-patterns.html) (not directly related to actors, but quite useful)
- Understanding actor concurrency, [pt.1](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2009/jw-02-actor-concurrency1.html), [pt.2](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2009/jw-03-actor-concurrency2.html) by Alex Miller

#### Papers

- [Disseration on making reliable distributed systems](http://erlang.org/download/armstrong_thesis_2003.pdf) by Joe Armstrong
- [Scalabale Component Abstractions](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~odersky/papers/ScalableComponent.html) by Philipp Haller and Martin Odersky
- [Event-based programming without inversion of control](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~odersky/papers/jmlc06.html) by Martin Odersky and Matthias Zenger
- [Actors with Multi-Headed Message Receive Patterns](http://ww2.cs.mu.oz.au/~sulzmann/talks/coordination08-talk.pdf) by Martin Sulzmann

#### Books

- [Actors In Scala](http://www.artima.com/shop/actors_in_scala) by Philipp Haller and Frank Sommers
- [Programming Erlang](http://pragprog.com/titles/jaerlang/programming-erlang) by Joe Armstrong
- [Erlang and OTP in Action](http://www.manning.com/logan/) by Martin Logan, Eric Merritt, and Richard Carlsson

#### Implementations

- [Akka Framework](http://doc.akkasource.org/) (alternative implementation of actors in Scala with a port of several Erlang behaviors and lots of other relized patterns for actors)
- [Scalaz Actors](http://docs.google.com/present/view?id=ddmk3f43_63zpg3jcgz) (actor compositions, strategies and promises)

#### Presentations

- [Actor Thinking](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Actor-Thinking) by Dale Schumacher
- [1000 Year-old Design Patterns](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/1000-Year-old-Design-Patterns) by Ulf Wiger
- [Actor-based Programming](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Actor-based-Programming) by Jamie Ridgway
- [Школа Актерского Мастерства](http://www.slideshare.net/remeniuk/ss-8206699) by Vasil Remeniuk

#### Examples from highscalability.com

- **[Simple queuing service (SQS)](http://highscalability.com/build-infinitely-scalable-infrastructure-100-using-amazon-services)** - this service provides an internet scale queuing service for storing messages. Distributed actors put work on the queue and take work off the queue. Typical use: a centralized work queue. You put jobs on the queue and different actors can pop work of the queue and process them when they get CPU time. Part of scalability. Have any number of producers and consumers. You don't worry about it. Queues are spread across multiple machines and multiple data centers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Design patterns for Agent / Actor based concurrent design.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568727/design-patterns-for-agent-actor-based-concurrent-design)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala actors - worst practices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549251/scala-actors-worst-practices)

Comment: link in above question *[posts on design with Scala actors](http://www.tikalk.com/category/tags/scala-actors)* not working.!

Comment: I gave some more additional resources and explanation in [Actor design pattern and real-world examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68097224/8295283) which I summarized in [Design Patterns with Actors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68097522/8295283).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is related to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549251/scala-actors-worst-practices), if not *exactly* the same!

It's not such a simple question because the **actor model** of concurrency allows for many different types of applications to be built, from a stateful single-VM application (with a few separate actor classes) to a stateless cluster of thousands of instances of an actor class.

The core principles are the same however:

- Never expose an actor's state
- Communicate solely via the passing of immutable messages

Answer (score 6):

I posted a blog on [learnings of actor development](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/learnings-from-actor-development/) in Scala a few weeks ago.  It's a post of a best practices and things to avoid based on a few years of experience with the paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

The book 'Reactive Design Patterns' is in the making at Manning.

See: https://www.manning.com/books/reactive-design-patterns